# Logcat on (embedded) test firmware

Tags: c++, c, testing, logcat, firmware

I am trying to create a test firmware using C code and would like to integrate LOGCAT onto it. Has anyone done this? or is this possible?

I search over the internet and LOGCAT is commonly used in Android development, haven't seen one for embedded systems/ hardware. Is there an equivalent for embeddeded test firmware?

Comment: Your question is too broad and asking for external libraries/code is also off-topic. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i belive your question is off topic

but in embedded systems we use serial port such as UART for monitoring and debugging
it works like terminal or LOGCAT and i didn't see any library that give you what you want

i always build my own command system or debug system over serial port